# Calendar(GridView) with Month Header(Google HeaderView)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-calendar

I have a calendar that I need to go 6 months back not 6 months forwards and having a little trouble making it go 6 months back. How would I make this calendar go 6 months back starting with the current month then scrolling down to the last 6 months?

Also, I am using the Google HeaderView to display a headerview for the gridview of the calendar. How would I add blank space after the end of each month to be able to place the header of that month in that area? The Google HeaderView seems to only populate once at the start of the GridView.

```
public class CalendarAt;ctivity extends Activity implements AppCompatCallback {
    private AppCompatDelegate delegate;
    Toolbar mToolbar;
    private HeaderGridView mGridView;
    private TextView mHeaderTextView;
    private LinearLayout calendar_view_header;
    private ImageView mCalendarButtonClicked, mCalendarButton, settingsBtn, settingsBtnChecked;
    private PopupWindow mPopUp;


    //default 6 months +- half a day
    private static final int DAYS_COUNT = 182;

    // current displayed month
    private Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    private EventListener eventListener = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        HashSet<Date> events = new HashSet<>();
        events.add(new Date());


        //Show Toolbar without extending AppCompatActivity
        delegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, this);
        delegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        delegate.setContentView(R.layout.calendar_main);
        delegate.setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mGridView = (HeaderGridView) findViewById(R.id.calendar_grid);
        settingsBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.settingsBtn);
        settingsBtnChecked = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.settingsBtnClicked);
        mCalendarButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eReceiptSearchBtn);
        mCalendarButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCalendarButtonClicked = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eReceiptSearchBtnClicked);
        calendar_view_header = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.calendar_view_header);
        mCalendarButtonClicked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        updateCalendar();
        mCalendarButtonClicked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

        settingsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPreferencesPopup();
                mCalendarButtonClicked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mCalendarButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Replace with just EReceipts for the specific date which was clicked on
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateCalendar() {
        updateCalendar(null);
    }

    private void updateCalendar(HashSet<Date> events) {
        Calendar calendar = (Calendar) currentDate.clone();
        int monthBeginningCell = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
        ArrayList<Date> cells = new ArrayList<>();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -monthBeginningCell);

        while (cells.size() < DAYS_COUNT) {
            cells.add(calendar.getTime());
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
        }

        String monthname=(String)android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM", new Date());
        String year = (String)android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy", new Date());
        Log.i("HERE", "updateCalendar: " + monthname + " " + year);
        View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.calendar_view_header, null);
        mGridView.addHeaderView(headerView);
        mGridView.setAdapter(new CalendarAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cells, events));
    }

    @Override
    public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSupportActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ActionMode onWindowStartingSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
        return null;
    }

    private class CalendarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Date> {
        private HashSet<Date> eventDays;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public CalendarAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Date> days, HashSet<Date> eventDays) {
            super(context, R.layout.control_calendar_day, days);
            this.eventDays = eventDays;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            Date date = getItem(position);
            int day = date.getDate();
            int month = date.getMonth();
            int year = date.getYear();
            String fullDate;

            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.control_calendar_day, parent, false);

                view.setBackgroundResource(0);
                if (eventDays != null) {
                    for (Date eventDate : eventDays) {
                        if (eventDate.getDate() == day && eventDate.getMonth() == month &&
                                eventDate.getYear() == year) {
                            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorBlack);
                            ((TextView) view).setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(day == Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                    Log.i("ADAM", "getView: " + day);


                }
            }
            ((TextView) view).setText(String.valueOf(date.getDate()));
            return view;
        }
    }

    public void setEventListener(EventListener eventListener) {
        this.eventListener = eventListener;
    }

    public interface EventListener {
        void onDayLongPress(Date date);
    }

    private void showPreferencesPopup() {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) CalendarActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View mPopUpLayout = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_btn_click,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.eReceiptsSettingsPopUp));
        mPopUp = new PopupWindow(mPopUpLayout, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        settingsBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        settingsBtnChecked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mPopUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        mPopUp.showAsDropDown(settingsBtn, 0, 0);

        mPopUp.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss() {
                mPopUp.dismiss();
                settingsBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                settingsBtnChecked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with just using the built in Calendar widget and not using a fully custom calendar. I was unable to get the custom Calendar to work how I wanted it.

With the built in Calendar widget I was able to only allow the user to only see up to current month while also stoping the calendar from going back more then 6 months at the current date of the users device.